# How to compute a canonical email?

Tags: email

Let's say I log into a website with my email address somewords@gmail.com. I cannot prevent someone to use the same just using a unique index because Some.Words@gmail.com would still be the same as per GMail rules. The soution would be to compute a canonical email and make it unique, but how to compute it?

I couldn't find any resource on this subject apart concerning GMail. Is it because it's the only mailbox provider doing this? If not are there general rules? If not what are provider's specific rules?

Comment: First - the two emails you have are distinct because of the punctuation mark (period) contained in the second email.  Second - the heck do you mean by canonical email?  Are you looking for a way to have an email that's not *quite* the same as somewords@gmail.com but still makes its way to somewords@gmail.com?

Comment: I know they are distinct but they link to the same mailbox so their canonical form would be stripped from dots and lowercased eg. But that's for GMail.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC5321 Section 4.1.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2) defines the possible charset:

```
Local-part = Dot-string / Quoted-string; MAY be case-sensitive
```

Where, eventually, it goes back to `atext` which is accidentally missing from the said RFC, but it's expanded elsewhere (as well as in errata):

```
   atext     =   ALPHA / DIGIT /     ; Printable US-ASCII
                   "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
                   "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
                   "&" / "'" /
                   "*" / "+" /
                   "-" / "/" /
                   "=" / "?" /
                   "^" / "_" /
                   "`" / "{" /
                   "|" / "}" /
                   "~"
```

so apart from the wide range charset available it also specifies that local parts MAY be case sensitive.

Apart from those formal rules there are no restriction on the interpretation of the local part, so **what you want doesn't exist**. It is always up to the local mailserver to interpret local parts, do equivalnce conversions, ignore characters and like.